I need tool recommendations for VRF/Automation
Any recommendations for VRF and off-chain automation/keepers? I’m coming from Ethereum and looking for things to use.

There are a variety to choose from when it comes to VRFs on Solana.
My non-exhaustive list to check out would include

SwitchBoard

Orao Network


Tutorials to check out
Switchboard: https://www.soldev.app/course/vrf
Orao Network: https://learn.calyptus.co/courses/13-build-an-onchain-guessing-game/
